why the loop order influence the efficiency of code in GEMM?
I'm writing a GEMM code in C++, but the loop order actually influences a lot to the efficiency. Code:
// The first edition
void gemm_cpu_naive(
    int* __restrict__ C, 
    const int* __restrict__ A, 
    const int* __restrict__ B, 
    const int n, 
    const int m, 
    const int k){
    for(int l=0; l<k; ++l)
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<m; ++j){
                C[i*m+j] += A[i*k+l] * B[l*m+j];
            }
}
// The second edition
void gemm_cpu_naive(
    int* __restrict__ C, 
    const int* __restrict__ A, 
    const int* __restrict__ B, 
    const int n, 
    const int m, 
    const int k){
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
            for(int l=0; l<k; ++l){
                C[i*m+j] += A[i*k+l] * B[l*m+j];
            }
}

n = 64, m = 64, k =64, the first edition costs 63 us, the second edition costs 118 us.
The memory access pattern seems the same, A in row-order, B in column-order.
I searched a lot, one answer is the forst edition frequent writes to the same memory location, which can cause cache thrashing.
I wonder it's the main cause of the huge difference of the efficiency? Or is the fact still undiscovered?

CPU cache behavior, most likely. One way is cache-friendly, and the other is not. Take smaller examples, and write out the values of all variables and results of all index calculations using pen and paper. Are there big jumps between index calculations in one loop, but not the other?

@Someprogrammerdude but isnt it as OP writes already? access pattern of C is the same and where there are jumps in indices of A in the first version, the second version has those jumps in accessing B

IMHO, duplicate of: Why is iterating 2D array row major faster than column major? (and many other questions as this fact is definitely not undiscovered). Feel free to edit the question if you think it is not a dup.

It is only necessary to look at the for loops to see the difference.
l is the slowest changing index of all but is being used to access consecutive values in memory. Even for modest sized arrays that forces a cache reload every access. On very large arrays it is disastrously slow.
for(int l=0; l<; ++l)
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
            C[i*m+j] += A[i*k+l] * B[l*m+j];

The second one is using a cache friendly indexing pattern which works through each cache line in order with out forcing multiple reloads. Once the cache has loaded everything in that cache line is quick. And the cache prediction will easily anticipate then next lines to bring in. You should always aim for cache local access which pretty much always means indexing along rows first and columns second if you want maximum performance.
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
        for(int l=0; l<k; ++l)
            C[i*m+j] += A[i*k+l] * B[l*m+j];

As @JeromeRichard correctly points out below the key to why this formulation is faster it that the address of C[i*m+j] is constant in the final loop on l so that the temporary sum can be held in a register and is only written back to memory just once when it has been computed. Thanks for the correction - now amended.
I think that this also means that only one cache line needs to be devoted to the C array accesses so that the linear dimensions of arrays A,B could be increased in size to 77 or 78 before the 48k of L1 cache is exhausted.
BTW Exact 2^N length arrays can also affect the behaviour of cache operation. Sometimes for good and on modern systems sometimes slow it down. I've been caught out by that quirk once doing big FFTs.

"The second one is using a cache friendly indexing pattern" No, B[l*m+j] is not "cache friendly". Both are bad for large matrices.

The OP ask for the 64x64x64 use-case and in this case, the 3 matrices fits in the L2 cache and even possibly the L1 (mostly on mainstream CPUs). Because of that, cache accesses are rather fast and the OP hypothesis about writes is certainly correct (but certainly not due to cache thrashing). In the second code, C[i*m+j] is a constant in the last loop so there is no need to load it from the cache nor to store it and this improve the efficiency of the loop (since more time is spent in the actual computation and the load ports are less saturated).

@JérômeRichard Yes you are right. The second form is preferred for exactly the reasons that you give. My bad.
